# How do you pass variables between classes when using pyqt threading?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, global-variables

```
class Menu(QWidget):

    def __init__(self, userID):
        ...

    def ExecuteSearch(self):
        global results
        searchquery = self.searchfield.text()
        print(searchquery)
        self.thread = QThread()
        self.worker = SearchThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(lambda: self.worker.run(searchquery))
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.thread.quit)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.worker.deleteLater)
        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.thread.start()
        self.searchbutton.setEnabled(False)
        self.thread.finished.connect(lambda: self.searchbutton.setEnabled(True))

        self.DisplayResults()

    def DisplayResults(self):
        global results
        print(results)
        for i in results:
            self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
            self.label.setObjectName("label")
            self.label.setText(f"Song Name: {i[1]}")
            self.label.setStyleSheet('{color: white}')
            self.label.setFont('Segoe UI Light', 15)
            self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label)
class SearchThread(QObject):
    
    finished =  pyqtSignal()

    def run(self, query):
        global results
        connection = sqlite3.connect("userData.db")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        payload = ['%'+query+'%']
        cursor.execute("SELECT SongID, SongName, ArtistID, Genres FROM SongInfo WHERE SongName LIKE ?", payload)
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        connection.close()
        self.finished.emit()
```

When the new thread of execution occurs on the button click, the results of an sql query are stored in a variable called results that I have set to be global after I couldn't find a way to pass the results variable to the Menu class without the use of globals. However, the results seems to have to different states. When printing results inside the SearchThread class, everything seems to be fine. However, when attempting to access results outside of the class, nothing is assigned to results and it cannot be iterated through. I was thinking that maybe when the thread of execution ends, the results variable is wiped clean.

Comment: In general, globals should be avoided, and this is even more important when dealing with threading, as there's no direct way to know when a global variable has changed (nor by what): if the threaded function requires some time for its completion (as sql queries sometime do), you could have different results when called from the main thread, even, theoretically, from the same function. If you want to communicate between threads, create a signal for the thread and emit the results from it.

Comment: I agree with @musicamante. In practice, add a parameter to your `finished` signal definition, pass the `results` in the `finished.emit` call, so that it will be passed to your slot handler, which means you have to create a new method in your `Menu` class (something like `on_search_results_received`) which takes a `result` argument, make your `thread.finished` connect to the method instead of to a lambda, and your method will have to do `self.searchbutton.setEnabled(True)` and whatever you want with the result.